# CSS Align Text with Select in the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align 2 div in the same line in html, but I can't find a way to do it. I tried using

```
   position:relative;
```

in the parent and

```
position:absolute;
```

in the childs, but no success, seems to only work with text.

[This is the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gonzalohernandez/hjLz8wz3/)

Comment: remove margin-right: 50% and add float: left to .right div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set both `div` elements to `float: left` and remove the `margin-right` from the `.right` class.

```
.right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

The `div` will now be on the same line, however it may yet not appear so. Remove the default `margin` for `p` elements and you're all set.

```
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/hjLz8wz3/2/)

Full code below:

```css
.left{
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    <span>SOME TEXT</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Mostrar:&nbsp</p>
    <select>
      <option value="todas">TEXT</option>
      <option value="leidas">TEXT</option>
      <option value="noLeidas">TEXT</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted, just a quick question, why is necessary to give both elements  float: left;  that does not seem "logic".

Comment: @Ghm you can acheive this by using span tag also.

Comment: The first `div` is floated to the left, and you want the second `div` to horizontally "stack" itself next to the first one. `float: right` would work too, but I wouldn't recommend it in this case. Just read up on `float` on the internet :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `margin-right: 50%;` and give `float: left;` to `.right`

```
.right {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjLz8wz3/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using display:inline-block.

```
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thinhn1992/kro2fxz3/

Comment: This only works because `.left` has `float: left`. If you remove the `float` it won't work with both widths at `50%` due to the nature of `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex;` in you `parent` class. And remove default margin from `p` tag.

**CSS**

```
 .parent {  
      overflow:hidden;
      background: yellow;
      width:90%;
      display:flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }

    p{
      margin:0;
    }
```

see the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hjLz8wz3/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this... fiddle link [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjLz8wz3/11/). You can set Mostrar in span tag

```
<span>Mostrar:</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Fiddle Link: 
[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/hjLz8wz3/10/)

With responsive layout

```
    .parent {  
  position: relative;

}
.left{
 border: 1px solid; 

}

.right {
  border: 1px solid;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 47.5em ) {
  .left { margin-right: 19.5em; }

    .right { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 18.75em; }   
}
```